# FedEx Tracking displays all dates in UTC timezone

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, fedex, timezone

has anyone figured out a way to display the fedex tracking screen in the correct timezones? aka, not UTC.

I've set the Magento timezone and the Server Timezones correctly. It's just the fedex tracking link that gives UTC dates and times, without warning on the frontend and the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it happens Mage overrides the timezone set in PHP and forces it to UTC in `app/Mage.php`. This is intended so that everything written to the DB is in UTC. The problem comes when the localization does not take into account the timezones of the places it talks about.

The work around to display all times in your store's timezone is to go into the getTracking method of `core/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Fedex.php`, although this should work for anything that implements `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface.` and replace

```
$this->_getXMLTracking($tracking);
```

With

```
            $og_tz = date_default_timezone_get();
            $store_tz = Mage::getStoreConfig('general/locale/timezone');
            date_default_timezone_set($store_tz);
            $this->_getXMLTracking($tracking);
            date_default_timezone_set($og_tz);
```

This will display the time in the store's timezone, which will not be exactly the same as the Fedex's tracking page, which by default displays times local to each stop.

I should mention that these changes should be in the app/code/local repository to preserve some upgradeability.

Hope someone finds this useful.